# python module stuck

Tags: c++, python, memory, module, boost-python

I have made a python module (with boost::python), which at some point creates an array (2D vector) of some massive objects. The total size of the objects is something like a few Gb. When starting execution of the program it hangs/stucks in the place where the array is initialized:

```
// my_object.h
class my_object{
   public:
   my_object(n){  create a bunch of 2D arrays (double, int, etc.) of size n x n }
};

// extension.cpp
vector<my_object> arr(t,my_object(n)); // t is big, n is big
```

If I decrease parameters t, and especially n, program works well. So it seems like there is some problem in either efficiency or possibility to initialize big array of big objects in python module. By the way, I have enough memory to store such a big array (reserve ~20 Gb or memory in pbs script, these are cluster computations), so the problem is hardly because of the memory (in that case i get clear message that it is enough memory). How can i overcome such a problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what facilities to you have to see what's happening when it hangs? Can you use `strace`, `dtrace`, `truss` or similar? Can you extract a core dump, stack trace dump or attach a debugger? Can you use `top` or something to see if the process is doing _anything_, and whether the allocated size is growing?

Comment: And another couple of questions: can you tell whether the locality of this memory changes at some threshold (ie, it doesn't fit on one node and starts paging)? Can you allocate this much memory in a plain C++ program without the Python wrapper?

Comment: the problem is that i submit a pbs job which calls the python to run the script involving module operations, so top (and other utilities) will hardly be useful, at least i don't know how to use them in such environment. In other part of the program i was reading ~1-2 Gb from files to the memory, but in much simpler array - it was fast, when I create array of such objects - the procedure is much slower.